# Resize SVG from Grumpicon

Tags: html, css, svg

I'm testing out grumpicon and so far it's pretty rad, but I'm not sure how to resize the SVG when the viewport shrinks?

When I do try to adjust the width and height, it appears that the containing `div` resizes but not the SVG itself:

[image]

So I'm not totally sure what to target within my CSS with Grumpicon to get the svg to resize.

Here is the CSS that is produced by Grumpicon:

```
.icon-fb-text-02-joined-white {
background-image: url('data:image/svg+xml;charset=US-ASCII,%3C%3Fxml%20version%3D%221.0%22%20encoding%3D%22utf-8%22%3F%3E%0D%0A%3C%21--%20Generator%3A%20Adobe%20Illustrator%2016.0.0%2C%20SVG%20Export%20Plug-In%20.%20SVG%20Version%3A%206.00%20Build%200%29%20%20--%3E%0D%0A%3C%21DOCTYPE%20svg%20PUBLIC%20%22-//W3C//DTD%20SVG%201.1//EN%22%20%22http%3A//www.w3.org/Graphics/SVG/1.1/DTD/svg11.dtd%22%3E%0D%0A%3Csvg%20version%3D%221.1%22%20id%3D%22Layer_1%22%20xmlns%3D%22http%3A//www.w3.org/2000/svg%22%20xmlns%3Axlink%3D%22http%3A//www.w3.org/1999/xlink%22%20x%3D%220px%22%20y%3D%220px%22%0D%0A%09%20width%3D%22322.297px%22%20height%3D%22208.707px%22%20viewBox%3D%220%200%20322.297%20208.707%22%20enable-background%3D%22new%200%200%20322...(LOTS OF HEXCODE)...162z%22/%3E%0D%0A%3C/g%3E%0D%0A%3C/svg%3E%0D%0A');
background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

And here it is in my HTML:

```
<script>
        /* grunticon Stylesheet Loader | https://github.com/filamentgroup/grunticon | (c) 2012 Scott Jehl, Filament Group, Inc. | MIT license. */
        window.grunticon=function(e){if(e&&3===e.length){var t=window,n=!(!t.document.createElementNS||!t.document.createElementNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/svg","svg").createSVGRect||!document.implementation.hasFeature("http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG11/feature#Image","1.1")||window.opera&&-1===navigator.userAgent.indexOf("Chrome")),o=function(o){var r=t.document.createElement("link"),a=t.document.getElementsByTagName("script")[0];r.rel="stylesheet",r.href=e[o&&n?0:o?1:2],a.parentNode.insertBefore(r,a)},r=new t.Image;r.onerror=function(){o(!1)},r.onload=function(){o(1===r.width&&1===r.height)},r.src="data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAIAAAAAAAP///ywAAAAAAQABAAACAUwAOw=="}};
    grunticon( [ "css/icons.data.svg.css", "css/icons.data.png.css", "css/icons.fallback.css" ] );
     </script>
    <noscript><link href="css/icons.fallback.css" rel="stylesheet"></noscript>
<div class="icon-fb-text-02-joined-white" style="width: 323px; height: 209px"></div>
```

Comment: Is it an `<img>`, or a `background-image`? If the first, try `max-wdtih:100%;max-height:100%`. If the second, try `background-size:contain` or `background-size:cover` as desired.

Comment: We need code to diagnose...an image is of little value.

Comment: @Paulie_D DAP! It didn't post it. I have edited the post.

Comment: It appears that the SVG specifies `width="322.297px" height="208.707px"` and a matching `viewBox`.  Which explains the width and height you have given your `<div>`.  If your SVG is overflowing those dimensions, then it might be that the content of your SVG does also.  It's hard to tell because you haven't provided the whole SVG.  Can you make a working fiddle so we can properly diagnose?